# Windows 10 UAP GridView ItemsPanel not wrapping properly

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-10

I'm porting an app from Win8.1 to Win10 (due to scope changes, it's a complete rewrite for UAP), and ran into an issue.

We are trying to display a few hundred items, grouped by their creation date (year and month) in a GridView. On W8.1 it was easy, create a GridView with a CollectionViewSource, set the GroupingStyle, and it would wrap the items so we can scroll vertically.

However, on W10, for some reason, all defined Panels defy this, and wrap the items horizontally, thus making lists instead of actual horizontally scrollable gridviews. This is not the behavior I want.

I tried with VariableSizedWrapGrid, which can do this, but only statically. It needs a MaximumRowsOrColumns value, which if I set, I can achieve wrapping, at a given height. As my items are fixed height (the VSWG ItemsHeight and ItemsWidth is set to 90, my items are 1 row 3 column), this results in vertically scrolling gridviews if the window height is less than the amount required to accommodate the items. I would like the items to automatically rearrange themselves so no vertical scrolling happens.

Is there a way to achieve the original W8.1 behavior of the Panels in Win10?

Comment: Actually, `GridView` has always been designed for displaying horizontally stacked items while `ListView` for vertically stacked items.

Comment: Justin, I realize that, but in Win10 UAP, the Panel acts like if it did not detect the height it can stretch to, and over-stretches.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem the other day, and was able to fix it by catching the `SizeChanged` event on the GridView and giving the underlying VariableSizedWrapGrid a maximum height that's equal to the ActualHeight of the GridView.

Basicly this would be like:

```
private void GridView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var innerVariableSizedWrapGrid = ControlHelper.FindChild<VariableSizedWrapGrid>(((GridView)AssociatedObject));

  if (innerVariableSizedWrapGrid != null)
    innerVariableSizedWrapGrid.MaxHeight = ((GridView)AssociatedObject).ActualHeight;
}
```

(ControlHelper is a VisualTree helper class to find children/parents. Many examples are available online, ask if you want my version)

My GridView looks like this: (I've omitted its styling and Itemsource)

```
<GridView 
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
  SizeChanged="GridView_SizeChanged">
  <GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Mind that the default Orientation of a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` was changed from Vertical to Horizontal (for desktop apps) in W10.
And the ScrollViewer its properties. These will make sure you cannot vertically scroll.

Oh, btw, I see you're using grouping as well, I had a few more problems with that. It seems that the first GroupItem's width is used for all GroupItems... I was able to fix it eventually. Check my [blog](http://wuyts.org/tom/blog/?p=109) for more details.